# "this" in JavaScript classes why it's throwing this error?

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

when it comes to `this` in javascript classes it suppose to refer to the class instances but at
`somechildmethod()` method it don't it throws an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` and I know this error will go away if I use the arrow function but I want to know why please!

```js
class parent {
  constructor(name, score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  }
  someparentmethod() {
    console.log("Hi!");
  }
}
class child extends parent {
  constructor(name, score, thirdprop) {
    super(name, score);
    this.thirdprop = thirdprop;
  }
  somechildmethod() {
    return function () {
      console.log(this.name);
    };
  }
}
const child1 = new child("zahal", 1);
const child2 = child1.somechildmethod();
child2();
```

Comment: Everything you need to know about `this` is explained in [How does the “this” keyword work?](/a/3127440/4642212). `child2()` is a contextless call of a `function` function, and `somechildmethod` is within a `class`, which implies strict mode, so `this` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Note that an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `return () => {   console.log(this.name); };` *would* work (inherit `this`).

Comment: and please read from YDKJS if you have time, https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Comment: @edemaine As the OP already described: _“and I know this error will go away if I use the arrow function”_.

Comment: thank you all I get it.